# Does Linux limit space on a USB drive?

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, flashing

I have Linux on a USB boot drive that should have 32GB of available space and when I boot Linux it only shows 7GB of space. Linux wont use the other 25GB of space.

I tried increasing the partition size and that fixed it but then Linux runs extremely slow.

I also tried Linux Mint, Ubuntu, Kali, Debian and had the same issue.

Comment: Maybe instead of increasing the partition size create a second partition.

Comment: @ChanganAuto So at the time of me asking this question I did not know that the usb  was storing data on ram instead of on the usb so when I increased the partition size linux ran so slow because reading/writing to ram is faster than reading/writing to a usb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux does not limit the amount of space on the USB drive. The process of creating a bootable dive, whether using Rufus, UNetbootin. or [other tool](https://alternativeto.net/software/rufus) **partitions** the USB drive. This created one ~7GB partition with Linux, and **other partitions**, totaling ~25 GB.

There are a number of partitions on that drive. Use a disk partitioning tool, such as [Ubuntu Disks](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/manage-ubuntu-hdd-disk-utility/), or [view them in terminal](https://linoxide.com/how-to-list-disks-in-linux/).
You should be able to access those other partitions *if they are formatted, not blank space*; just mount them.

Comment: @RedRaptor You need to understand the differences between and installer/live and an installed system. Using the aforementioned tools to burn an ISO to the USB makes installation/live media. It's NOT the same as installing the system into an external drive, for which you'd need TWO USBs, one to boot from and the other as the target for installation. The installation media, being "made" from a drive image (ISO) will burn that exact size regardless of the USB flash drive's capacity.

Comment: When installing the target being an internal or external drive is irrelevant.